# Gl3w compilation errors: invalid conversion from 'PROC ... to void*'

Tags: windows, opengl

Setting up gl3w in my computer: 2 errors that I have no idea how to resolve are being thrown:

Function that's built by Gl3w script which has the errors:

```
static void *get_proc(const char *proc)               - line 19
{
void *res;

res = wglGetProcAddress(proc);                    - line 23, first error
if (!res)
    res = GetProcAddress(libgl, proc);        - line 25, second error
return res;
}
```

Build errors:

```
||=== LearnOPG, Debug ===|
C:\CodeBlocks\LearnOPG\gl3w.c||In function 'void* get_proc(const char*)':|

C:\CodeBlocks\LearnOPG\gl3w.c|23|error: invalid conversion from 'PROC {aka int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)()}' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]|

C:\CodeBlocks\LearnOPG\gl3w.c|25|error: invalid conversion from 'FARPROC {aka int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)()}' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]|

||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some compilers/platforms are less picky than others. Implicitly converting function pointers to `void*` and back is not guaranteed to be possible by C or C++. But GL3W's code expects it to work; obviously, it was not tested with more strict compilers/platforms.

You should probably file a bug report on it [with the GL3W people](https://github.com/shakesoda/gl3w). Granted, it doesn't seem to be being actively worked on, but they might fix it.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to cast it to (void*), and it seemed to work? I've got other errors to deal with now. Thanks for the new gl3w comment, also!

Comment: Additionaly, if it isn't bothersome/you're not busy/you don't mind, would you give some slightly detailed instructions on how to set up gl3w?

Comment: I've ran the script, and put both the gl3w.c, gl3w.h, and arbsomething.c, directly into my project's source files, and 
#include "gl3w.h"in my main.cpp.
Is this the right way?

Comment: Ah, I finally got it working, needed a "opengl32" link. Thanks for the answer! I think I'll do the steps myself on a question :)